# Testing Caught Exceptions in JUnit

Tags: java, junit, exception

I am trying to create a test that verifies that my *code* (see below for the pseudocode) correctly catches an exception. I know that JUnit is able to test whether the code throws an exception with the following code:

```
@Test (expected = ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.class)
```

However, my original code of the software I'm testing catches this exception and prints a message

```
catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException E) {
    System.out.print("The output should be of even length!");
}
```

Is there any way for JUnit to verify this message? Or should I change something in my catch phrase?

Note: I have read that I should use the following:

```
@Rule 
public ExpectedException thrown = ExpectedException.none();

@Test
public void decodeOddLengthInput() {
    thrown.expect(ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.class);
    thrown.expectMessage("Message");
```

But the program crashes because it doesn't recognize the `ExpectedException` object.

Pseudocode of the method I am trying to test (don't post the exact thing because of privacy reasons):

```
public String decode(byte[] array){
try{
for(int i= 0; i<array.length; i= i+2){
//basically it crashes when input is an array of odd length (because of i=i+2)
   get byte at array[i] and turn it into a string;
   }
 }
catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException E) { System.out.print("Message!");}

  return string ;
  }
```

Comment: If the method is catching the exception, it's not exposed to the calling method, and you can't test for it. You can test that the exception _isn't_ thrown (by reproducing the scenario where you would expect it to occur -- if it was thrown your test would fail). Any exceptions caught by the method are not part of its signature, and should be considered implementation details, outside of the scope of any specific unit test.

Comment: This question probably indicates there's something amiss about the method you're testing.  If it's a method that's supposed to return a result, then having it catch exceptions, print out messages, and then continue as if everything were hunky dory, is probably not what it should be doing.  If it's a method that just does stuff and prints the output or prints an error message, it will be hard to unit test anyway.  In the latter case, you might want to refactor the method into one that does the computation and one that prints results, and unit-test the first one.

Comment: can you also post your code?

Comment: I thought that catching the error was better because then the user would know that he/she need only input an even sized byte array.

Answer (score 1):

Your software method isn't re-throwing the exception with a message. It is simply eating the exception by printing the message. In this case, calling test method will never know about this exception, so you can not test this scenario or verify the message.

Answer (score 1):

with Junit5 it is now possible to assert a method that returns an exception like this:

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions;

class YourServiceImplTest {

private YourService subject;

@Test
public void decodeOddLengthInput() {
    // Act and Assert
    Assertions.assertThrows(YourException.class, () -> {
      subject.getAll();
    }, "Error message expected");
 }
}
```